# Inserting Data Into Database

Tags: mysql

I'm haveing a problem where i want to do insert info into my database. But there is some new info some old info and some from a diffrent table.

What i need is to get

a Stage namn from a ComboBox

a Personal Number from a diffrent table where i get a namn from a ComboBox

2 diffrent sets of number from textboxes.

I cant find how to do all things att once or rather i need the stage namn and the pnr becouse there Foreign keys

Psedu code would be something like

Insert into Safty(PNr , StageNamn , Day , Time) Values (Where Persoanl.Namn = ComboBox1 , ComboBox2 , TextBox1 , TextBox2)

the other 2 is new info so not needed in the first statment i can use a alter to add them in later.

thank you for any help that can be given.

ps and now i cant change the table so it uses the namn instead of pnr becouse of how the other tables are built

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. I have no idea what your exact problem is. Also you should include the code you have already.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to do `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) SELECT something, somethingelse, "some string", ... FROM secondTable`

Comment: I adde in a somewhat PseduCode but im sure its wrong. The thing is im not sure how to write the code att all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Safty (Pnr, StageNamn, Day, Time)
SELECT Pnr, :ComboBox2, :TextBox1, :TextBox2
FROM Personal
WHERE Namn = :ComboBox1
```